# Speeding up Ruby code to make faster/more API calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I have the following code:

```
list_entities = [{:phone => '0000000000', :name => 'Test', :"@i:type => '1'},{:phone => '1111111111', :name => 'Demo', :"@i:type => '1'}]

list_entities.each do |list_entity|
          phone_contact = PhoneContact.create(list_entity.except(:"@i:type"))
          add_record_response = api.add_record_to_list(phone_contact, "API Test")

          if add_record_response[:add_record_to_list_response][:return][:list_records_inserted] != '0'
            phone_contact.update(:loaded_at => Time.now)
          end

        end
```

This code is taking an array of hashes and creating a new `phone_contact` for each one. It then makes an api call (`add_record_response`) to do something with that `phone_contact`. If that api call is successful, it updates the `loaded_at` attribute for that specific `phone_contact`. Then it starts the loop over.

I am allowed something like 7200 api calls per hour with this service - However, I'm only able to make about 1 api call every 4 seconds right now.

Any thoughts on how I could speed this code block up to make faster api calls?

Comment: A better approach would maybe be to spawn multiple processes to make parallel calls. If you are making a call to an external API, you probably can't do much to optimize the response time

Comment: Another better approach is to use a background job (preferably with something like Resque). You will have the double-benefit of making your Rails app faster plus being able to spawn as many workers as necessary to get the API speed you need.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for the suggestions. I'll start looking into those options now.

Comment: Which ruby version are you running it on? You could get some milliseconds from that.

Comment: I am using ruby 2.0.0

Comment: Depending on your use case resque may be a little heavy handed. How often do you need to run this job? Depending on your requirements I would think a simple thread pool and queue would do what you are looking for. Resque would require you to bring in redis and can be a lot of overhead if you just need to run this locally or a couple of times per day.

Comment: Yep, this is going to run once per week ideally. Occasionally it will be ran locally twice a week, but definitely no need for overkill. I'll look into your answer and see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a thread pool. You can define a unit of work to be done and the number of threads you want to process the work on. This way you can get around the bottleneck of waiting for the server to response on each request. Maybe try something like (disclaimer: this was adapted from http://burgestrand.se/code/ruby-thread-pool/)

```
require 'thread'

class Pool
  def initialize(size)
    @size = size
    @jobs = Queue.new

    @pool = Array.new(@size) do |i|
      Thread.new do
        Thread.current[:id] = i

        catch(:exit) do
          loop do
            job, args = @jobs.pop
            job.call(*args)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def schedule(*args, &block)
    @jobs << [block, args]
  end

  def shutdown
    @size.times do
      schedule { throw :exit }
    end

    @pool.map(&:join)
  end
end


p = Pool.new(4)

list_entries.do |list_entry|
  p.schedule do
    phone_contact = PhoneContact.create(list_entity.except(:"@i:type"))
    add_record_response = api.add_record_to_list(phone_contact, "API Test")

    if add_record_response[:add_record_to_list_response][:return][:list_records_inserted] != '0'
      phone_contact.update(:loaded_at => Time.now)
    end

    puts "Job #{i} finished by thread #{Thread.current[:id]}"
  end
  at_exit { p.shutdown }
end
```